# How to use ThreeJS' FontLoader in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, three.js

I want to create text in three.js. So I am trying to load the font and it is failing. Why?

```js
const loader = new FontLoader();

loader.load(
  'http://localhost:8080/src/store/fonts/noto_sans_kr_regular.json',
  font => {
    const color = 0x006699;

    const matLite = new Three.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: color,
      transparent: true,
      opacity: 0.4,
      side: Three.DoubleSide,
    });

    const message = '   Three.js\nSimple text.';

    const shapes = font.generateShapes(message, 100);

    const geometry = new Three.MeshBasicMaterial(shapes);

    geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    const xMid =
      -0.5 *
      (geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x);

    geometry.translate(xMid, 0, 0);

    // make shape ( N.B. edge view not visible )

    const text = new Three.Mesh(geometry, matLite);
    text.position.z = -150;
    state.scene.add(text);
  },
);
```

Above is my source code and below are the methods I have tried.

```js
loader.load('http://localhost:8080/src/store/fonts/noto_sans_kr_regular.json'
  loader.load('http://localhost:8080/@/store/fonts/noto_sans_kr_regular.json'
  loader.load('/noto_sans_kr_regular.json'
  loader.load('@/store/fonts/noto_sans_kr_regular.json'
  loader.load('/src/store/fonts/noto_sans_kr_regular.json'
  loader.load('./fonts/noto_sans_kr_regular.json'
```

This is the error code.

[image]

This is the path to the font file.

[image]

I don't know if other parts of the code are needed. sorry.

Comment: Didn't used Vue2 for a while but `loader.load('@/store/fonts/noto_sans_kr_regular.json'` seems okay in terms of path. Maybe also try `loader.load('@/src/store/fonts/noto_sans_kr_regular.json'`. Otherwise, you're having a `.json` file here, not really a font file (`.otf`, `.ttf`, `.woff` etc...) so this is probably one other issue to fix.

Comment: Also, not sure why you have it inside of `store` (used for Vuex in general).

Comment: @kissu  It doesn't work, but thanks for the reply. The reason the path is a store is because we moved it to test the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure how to load that from a given directory, but `public` works with the following code

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <canvas ref="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { FontLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js';
import { TextGeometry } from 'three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js';
import { Mesh, MeshNormalMaterial, WebGLRenderer, PerspectiveCamera, Scene } from 'three'

export default {
  mounted() {
    const loader = new FontLoader()
    const scene = new Scene();
    const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, 800 / 600)
    camera.position.set(70, 0, 100)

    const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: this.$refs.canvas,
    })
    renderer.setSize(800, 600)
    loader.load("/macondo_font.json", function (font) {
      const textGeometry = new TextGeometry("Hello world!", {
        font,
        size: 20,
        height: 5,
        curveSegments: 12
      });
      const material = new MeshNormalMaterial();
      const textMesh = new Mesh(textGeometry, material);

      scene.add(textMesh);
      renderer.render(scene, camera)
    });
  },
}
</script>
```

The font needs to be sent to [facetype.js](https://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/) for a generated JSON file too (a `.ttf` or alike is indeed not available in the 3D realm).

Here is the structure of my project + the [Macondo font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Macondo) I used in my example.

[image]